# The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_TitleMember". The conflict occurred in database "ParishDBSQL", table "dbo.Titles", column 'title_id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

**controller**

**Get Action**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
       var member = (from h in db.Members
       join f in db.Titles on h.title_id equals f.title_id
                       where h.m_id == id
                      select new
                      {
                          title_id = h.title_id,
                        }).First();
var viewmodel = new MembersViewModel();
        viewmodel.title_id = member.title_id;
ViewBag.Titles = new SelectList(db.Titles.ToList(), "title_id", "Titles", viewmodel.title_id);

return View(viewmodel);

    }
```

**Post Action**

```
public ActionResult Edit(MembersViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
var member = db.Members.Find(vm.m_id);
          member.title_id = vm.title_id;
   ViewBag.Titles = new SelectList(db.Titles.ToList(), "title_id", "Titles", vm.title_id);

                db.Members.Attach(member);
                db.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;    
 db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        return View(vm);
```

**View**

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label>Title</label>

                @Html.DropDownList("Titles")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title_id)
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Model**

```
 public partial class Title
    {
    public Title()
    {
        this.Heads = new HashSet<Head>();
        this.Members = new HashSet<Member>();
    }

    public int title_id { get; set; }
    public string Titles { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Head> Heads { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

**Viewmodel**

```
public class MembersViewModel
{
    public int m_id { get; set; }
    public string titles { get; set; }
    public int title_id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to update a title_id using a dropdownlist on my members table table but I get the error that is shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think that the error is in this line

```
member.title_id = vm.title_id
```

maybe  `vm.title_id` it is not found in primary table and it could not be a foreign key. Check the correct value of this variable

if it doesn't solve your problem looking at your code I saw some thinghs that I didn't understand very well.

try to change your code in this way

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var member = db.Members.Find(vm.m_id);
    member.title_id = vm.title_id;
    ViewBag.Titles = new SelectList(db.Titles.ToList(), "title_id", "Titles", vm.title_id);   
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

1. Usually I use `db.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;` if I have to do other changes   before `db.SaveChanges();`
2. `member` is already attched to your table. Why do you `db.Members.Attach(member);`

**update**

change

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.title_id, ViewBag.Titles)
```

into

`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.title_id, (SelectList) ViewBag.Titles)`

because `ViewBag` is a dynamic object

Comment: member.title_id = vm.title_id yet it is here because it gives me 0 instead of a valid number and the code you did is the same with mine

Comment: try second approach that I have written

Comment: be sure that `vm.title_id` exist in your primary table!

Comment: yes is there. and db.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified; i use this 1 for other data that i want to save.

Comment: are you sure that the value exist in primary table? maybe you did not perform `db.SaveChanges()` yet

Comment: but you have accepted the other answer! which answer solve your problem?

Comment: cause you didnt write dropdownfor

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the drop down list in the view. You really want to initialize it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.title_id, ViewBag.Titles)
```

The way you're initializing it now causes the selected value to be passed as a query string parameter - you should see the URL being posted to as `...?Titles=1` for example.

Comment: i get that error even before i run the project "has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax."